# one time password (OTP) expiry leeway

Tags: passwords, one-time-password

how does one set a leeway for timed expiry that will allow for a margin of error for example: 1 Minute?

Currently this is my rough implementation, I must add another check for the last minute in case that the server receives the message 00:01:00 and client sends 00:00:59;

```
/**Client**/
int minutesNow = timeInSeconds()/60;
String mySignature = genAlgo(minutesNow, firstPassword);
sendToServer(mySignature);

/**Server**/
int minutesNow = timeInSeconds()/60;
String userPassword = getUserPassword();
boolean result = verifySig(mySignature, userPassword, minutesNow);
if(!result)
{
   result = verifySig(mySignature, userPassword, --minutesNow);
}
```

this question is an elaboration of
[Password Reset Link Expiry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8863082/password-reset-link-expiry) ... I need more details into the time +/-

Answer (score 1):

You need just make several checks in server-side: for the current minute, minute ago and minute in future.

It would be look something like this:

```
/**Server**/
int validationWindow = 1; // in minutes
int minutesNow = timeInSeconds()/60;
String userPassword = getUserPassword();

int timeToCheck = minutesNow - validationWindow; 
boolean result = verifySig(mySignature, userPassword, timeToCheck);
while (!result && timeToCheck <= minutesNow + validationWinwow) {
    result = verifySig(mySignature, userPassword, ++timeToCheck);
}
```